# PHP Preg Match All fails when matching string with HTML.

Tags: php, regex, string, obfuscation, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match the class names in the following.

```
<section className="content_main_container">
<article className="comment_user_propic">
```

But only the "article" className is matched.

I've tried the following.

```
function comments(){
    $str = <<<EOT

    '<section className="content_main_container">
    <article className="comment_user_propic">'

EOT;

return $str;
}

class obfusicate {  

    function change($str, $prefix){

        preg_match_all('#'.$prefix.'="(.*?)"#',$str,$parts);

        $array_len          = count($parts[1]);
        $class_count        = 0;
        $c_array            = [];

        foreach($parts[1] as $part){
            $rand_name      = self::rand_g();
            $c_array[$part] = $rand_name;   

            ++$class_count;     
            $str_1      = str_replace($part, $rand_name, $str);
        }

        return ['array'=>$c_array, 'string'=>$str_1];
    }
}

$obs        = new obfusicate;
$result     = $obs->change(comments(), 'className');

echo var_dump($result['string']);
```

Comment: Why not do it with a DOM parser?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its not HTML, its React. So the tags are in react. And I want to parse a small react js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
    foreach($parts[1] as $part){
        $rand_name      = self::rand_g();
        $c_array[$part] = $rand_name;   

        ++$class_count;     
        $str_1      = str_replace($part, $rand_name, $str); //each time you start over replacing from $str and you lose your last $str_1 value
    }

    return ['array'=>$c_array, 'string'=>$str_1]; //Assigned after the loop so only the last $str_1 value is stored
```

EDiT: Look at my comment in the last line

Comment: To solve it you can just avoid using $str_1, simply: 
    $str = str_replace($part, $rand_name, $str);

Comment: I'm just new on stack overflow ;)